# how to use methods in a module when it is assigned to a variable

Tags: python, list, methods, append, attributeerror

I have assigned a variable **f**    to a method **list.append**. How can I use **f** to call that method? I have tried the following but it produces error.

```
f = list.append
a = []
a.f([1])

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'f'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass it a list to act on:

```
f(a, 1)
```

But... Why do you need this? It's quite unusual...

As an alternative:

```
a = []
f = a.append
f(1)
```

`f` now is bound method (to list `a`).

Comment: i wanted to call a function from a given string that contains the function name. i succeeded to my user defined one but failed in calling methods inside a module. Thanks it works. I am a newbie in python. So i wanted to ask another question. How do you know that f now takes two arguments?

Comment: @SabbirAhmed When you write python classes, you almost always do this: `def method(self, argument)`. The `self` there is an explicit reference to the current object, so when you are writing `a = []; a.append(1)` this is actually identical to `a = []; list.append(a, 1)`. I know this because of experimenting in iPython and reading docs, also watching PyCon presentations is really useful.